# What is the SQL Query to solve the following Problem?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

Flutter App which save all the day to day task.
And trying to show all past data which includes date and total tasks and completed task of Particular Date.
From internet search I came to the conclusion about Advance SQL Query with Count and all Sort of condition.

I have tried,

'SELECT $TASK_COLUMN_DATE_YEAR, $TASK_COLUMN_DATE_MONTH, $TASK_COLUMN_DATE_DAY, COUNT ($TASK_COLUMN_ID) as $total, SUM(CASE WHEN $TASK_COLUMN_ISDONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as $completed FROM $TABLE_NAME_TASK WHERE (Condition Goes Here)';

but stuck in middle of dungeon.

[image: Table Structure]

Any suggestion or different approach will be appreciates. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it.

SQL Solution.

"select year, month, day, 
sum(case when isDone = 1 then 1 else 1 end) as totalTask ,
sum(case when isDone = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as completedTask 
from Task group by year, month, day
"